# rendering a fancy radio button that without using explicit pixels to position the radio

Tags: html, css

I cannot get the inner div of the radio button to center and I have resorted to using explicit pixels to get it close enough.  How can I center it accurately without using explicit pixels?

```css
.radio__container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 38px;
}

.radio__container input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

.checkable-group__fieldset label {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.radio__container input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
  border: 3px solid #0065bd;
}

.radio__container label:before {
  content: "";
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  border: 2px solid #0065bd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
}

.radio__container input[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  left: 9px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 10px solid #0065bd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #0065bd;
}

.radio__content {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  -ms-flex: 1 1;
  flex: 1 1;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple HTML/CSS/JS Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div class="radio__container radio">
        <input
          type="radio"
          id="epandable_0"
          name="epandable"
          data-selector="radio-foo"
          aria-describedby="epandable-legend"
          value="foo"
          checked=""
        /><label for="epandable_0" id="epandable" class="label__default"
          ><div class="radio__content">foo</div></label
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `display: flex` and `align-items: center` to `.radio__container` to solve it.

```css
.radio__container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 38px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.radio__container input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

.checkable-group__fieldset label {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.radio__container input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
  border: 3px solid #0065bd;
}

.radio__container label:before {
  content: "";
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  border: 2px solid #0065bd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
}

.radio__container input[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  left: 9px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 10px solid #0065bd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #0065bd;
}

.radio__content {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  -ms-flex: 1 1;
  flex: 1 1;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple HTML/CSS/JS Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div class="radio__container radio">
        <input
          type="radio"
          id="epandable_0"
          name="epandable"
          data-selector="radio-foo"
          aria-describedby="epandable-legend"
          value="foo"
          checked=""
        /><label for="epandable_0" id="epandable" class="label__default"
          ><div class="radio__content">foo</div></label
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change position to absolute and give height to 100%;

```css
.radio__container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 38px;
}

.radio__container input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

.checkable-group__fieldset label {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.radio__container input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
  border: 3px solid #0065bd;
}

.radio__container label:before {
  content: "";
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  border: 2px solid #0065bd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
}

.radio__container input[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  left: 9px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 10px solid #0065bd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #0065bd;
}

.radio__content {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  -ms-flex: 1 1;
  flex: 1 1;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple HTML/CSS/JS Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div class="radio__container radio">
        <input
          type="radio"
          id="epandable_0"
          name="epandable"
          data-selector="radio-foo"
          aria-describedby="epandable-legend"
          value="foo"
          checked=""
        /><label for="epandable_0" id="epandable" class="label__default"
          ><div class="radio__content">foo</div></label
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```